# How can I migrate ECS Instance across Dedicated Host

Tags: dedicated-server, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I have an Alibaba Cloud ECS and want to migrate across my Dedicated Host (DDH). 
How can I do the same and Is there any limitation on the ECS.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this documentation clarify how to do it [enter link description here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/68988.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.19.1c1339149wARz7)

1. Log on to the ECS console.
2. In the left-side navigation pane, click Instances.
3. Select a region.
4. Optional. In the upper-right corner of the instance list, click the Set Display Items icon, and on the dialog box, click Dedicated Host,and then click OK.
5. You can view the Dedicated Host column in the table, which helps you locate the DDH that an ECS instance is hosted on.
6. Find an ECS instance, and in the Actions column, select More >Instance Status > Stop to stop the instance.
7. When the instance is in the Stopped status, in the Actions column, select More > Instance Settings > Modify DDH Deployment.
8. On the dialog box, select a DDH and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Procedure to migrate ECS Instance across Dedicated Host is as follows:

> 1. Log on to the ECS console.
> 2. Navigate to Instances List
> 3. Select the region
> 4. Click Settings Icon and enable dedicated host column view, Locate DDH where the ECS is Hosted On
> 5. Stop the instance
> 6. Click Actions--> More --> Instance Settings --> Modify DDH Deployment, dialog  box will appear, select the DDH and then click Ok.

Note: Refresh the instance list until the Dedicated Host information is updated. The instance starts automatically.